# Paypal IPN validation does not working

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

showing me an error during the time of paypal IPN validation. I have used the paypal IPN code sample for PHP (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/#listener)

```
while (!feof($fp)) { // While not EOF
   $res = fgets($fp, 1024); // **Showing error from this line**
}

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: fgets() [function.fgets]: SSL: Connection reset by peer
Filename: controllers/IPN_Listner.php
Line Number: 79
```